# Finding all documents in a MongoDB collection takes very long

Tags: java, mongodb, performance

I have this empty collection in my database that I just started working on (obviously) and I have log messages which print out how long it takes to loop through all the documents in this collection. The problem is that even as an empty collection, it always takes ~100ms to finish loading all of them. This only happens for a single collection and not my other one (see screenshot) https://prnt.sc/jkg428

Here is my code for loading gangs

```
private void loadGangs() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int amount = 0;

    for (Document document : gangsCollection.find()) {
        loadGang(document);
        amount++;
    }

    Core.log("Loaded &e" + amount + " &fgang" + (amount == 1 ? "" : "s") + " in &e" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + "ms.");
}

private void loadGang(Document document) {
    Gang gang = new Gang(document.getString("_id"), UUID.fromString(document.getString("leader")));

    List<UUID> members = Lists.newArrayList();

    for (String uuidAsString : (ArrayList<String>) document.get("members")) {
        members.add(UUID.fromString(uuidAsString));
    }

    gang.setMembers(new HashSet<>(members));
}
```

And here's my code for loading accounts

```
private void loadAccounts() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int amount = 0;

    for (Document document : accountsCollection.find()) {
        loadAccount(document);
        amount++;
    }

    Core.log("Loaded &e" + amount + " &faccount" + (amount == 1 ? "" : "s") + " in &e" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + "ms.");
}

private void loadAccount(Document document) {
    Account account = new Account(UUID.fromString(document.getString("_id")));

    if (document.containsKey("gang")) {
        account.setGang(Gang.getGang(document.getString("gang")));
    }
}
```

Both are relatively similar when it comes to querying yet loading gangs takes a significantly greater amount of time than it does to load accounts, even when both collections are empty. What could I do about this?
Thanks.

Edit/Side-note: Everything works perfectly, I am only concerned about the performance here especially when it comes time to have 1000+ different accounts and/or gangs.

Comment: Both `find()` conditions are completely unbound without criteria and you are iterating lists with calls. That's not good. What are you actually trying to do here? You are probably after some sort of server side aggregation which could actually be of course executed on the server rather than returning all the documents.

Comment: Why cant you build HashSet<> directly, instead building List first?

Comment: This doesn't look like a MongoDB issue to me. The codes `loadGang` and `loadAccount` do different things, so you can't compare them directly vs. each other. I believe the timings not only count the time MongoDB returns result, but you're measuring the timings of the two functions as a whole.